# Create Generic Class Depending on Type of Runtime Variable

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to create an instance of a class of type `T` depending on the type of a runtime variable?

For example:

```
var myType = myVariable.GetType();
var myTestClass = new TestClass<myType>();
```

This will not compile but hopefully shows what I'm trying to achieve.

Is there a way?

**EDIT**

Say the class is like this:

```
public class TestClass<T>
{     
    public string StringValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.TypeValue == null ? string.Empty : this.TypeValue.ToString();
        }   
    }

    public T TypeValue { get; set; }  
}
```

If I did something like:

`var test1 = TestClass((dynamic)x); // x is an int`

I would be able to set like `test1.TypedValue = 10`

If I did something like:

`var test2 = TestClass((dynamic)y); // y is a bool`

I would be able to set like `test2.TypedValue = true`

At the moment I get an error stating

> cannot implicitly convert type int to TestClass (or bool to TesClass)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use reflection:

```
object myTestClass = Activator.CreateInstance(
    typeof(TestClass<>).MakeGenericType(myType));
```

If your `TestClass<T>` implements a non-generic interface or has a non-generic base-class, it will be more usable:

```
ITestClass myTestClass = (ITestClass) Activator.CreateInstance(
    typeof(TestClass<>).MakeGenericType(myType));
```

You can also cheat with `dynamic` (which does the reflection for you, and caches the optimized strategy for performance, etc):

```
Evil((dynamic)myVariable);
...
void Evil<T>(T val)
{
    var myTestClass = new TestClass<T>();
    //...
}
```

Comment: +1 for cheating .. evilishly

Comment: @quetzalcoatl actually, I did screw up the call; fixed in edit

Comment: @davy if `myVariable` is `int`, then what is `myProp` ? what declares `myProp`? because it clearly isn't the `int`...

Comment: @davy no, not really; an actual example would really help

Comment: @Marc - I'v edited the question.  Happy to clarify further if required.